# Is there an easier way to view replays?

Tags: dota

I am trying to do some replay viewing practices.  Unfortunately, the WC3 replay viewing doesn't offer user friendly controls. I was wondering if there is any application or plugin to improve the replay viewing.
For example, I want to be able to scroll the replay to certain parts I need, rather than waiting to get there by increasing the playback speed to x8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there is no tool to enable you to jump/scroll directly to a point.

However, you can speed up the replay speed more than the standard x8 using [Replay Seeker](http://www.playdota.com/forums/showthread.php?t=506&highlight=replay+seeker).

**WARNING: It can still be buggy.**